# Cals attributes meaning

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, cals-tables

I've been working on cals tables, and i came across some line as below.

```
<entry colname="col2" align="left" valign="top"><para>Powers of Attorney</para></entry>
```

Here i'm unable to understand what `entry colname="col2"` is for and how to render it in my XSLT. please let me know what is the use of this and also please suggest me some CALS Tables XSLT tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CALS format for tables includes a `colspec` which defines the columns and (optionally) gives a name to each column.  Individual table cells can then specify which columns they appear in using `colname` (for a single column) or `namest`/`nameend` (spanning multiple columns), which cross-reference to the names in the `colspec`.  In the absence of any `colname`/`namest`/`nameend` attributes the columns will lay out from left to right like the `td` elements in an HTML table, but with name cross references entries may appear out of order.

Furthermore, row-spanning is handled by a cell on one row having `morerows="number"`, so when processing one row you have to keep track of whether there are any cells spanning into this row from the row above, and if so which columns they are in - it's very much an iterative algorithm which is not particularly easy to handle in a declarative language like XSLT.

Comment: Hi @IanRoberts, Thanks for the reply. Can you please let me know how i can use it in my XSLT for rendering. Just a small example would be great help. Thanks again

Comment: @user2423959 it depends entirely on what sort of XML or HTML you want to generate.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17820393/592139) has an example of one way to approach it for conversion to Office XML, taking account of row spans but not column spans.  As you can see it's rather ugly and complex already...

Comment: my sample XML Data with my XSLT and current HTML are in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134137/cals-table-not-properly-getting-created, can you please look into it. Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this website for more info on CALS tables.

http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/cals.table.html